# Hibernate subclass id generation in table per subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

When im using table-per-subclass strategy my base (parent class) contains compound primary.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XXX")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "XXX", sequenceName = "XXX",  allocationSize = 1)
private Long systemId;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long version;
```

So, all entities that extend this (as i got it) inherit ids and its annotated properties.
The problem, is that when i create a new Parent entity, the primary is being created from sequence, thats ok. But when i create subclass instance it increments my parent id i dont need (creates a new primary from seq.), `coz i use table-per-subclass and primaries gottta be the same.

Question: how to supress id generation in Subclasses?

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(
    {
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "systemId"),
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "version")
    }
)
public class SUb extends Parent {

public SUb (Parent t) {
    super(t);
}

public SUb () {
}
...

... no ids...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Subclass is created it will issue two inserts:

1. one in the base class
2. one in the sub class

The subclass doesn't inherit the @Ids, but instead it uses the:

- systemId
- version

as FK to the associated columns of the Base table.

So while the base class has a primary key composed of those two columns:

- a sequence generated systemId
- a manually assigned version

The subclass should have:

- a sequnceId column with a FK to the base sequnceId column
- a version column with a FK to the base version column

So the sequence shouldn't be called twice while inserting a sub class entity.

Can you confirm that the database tables are following this design?

Comment: Yeah, but i dont have @id`s in Sub classes. hibernate even cant allowd that. And i have PrimaryKeyJoinColumns with 2 columns of my compound PK

Comment: I thought the second one is from the subclass. In this case the second column identifier is assigned.

Comment: Please post both the  base and the subclass to check further.

Comment: its very large i suppose it`d be bad style approch.

Comment: You said subclass should have aa sequnceId column with a FK to the base sequnceId column, and so on. So in my case ther isnt `coz it is said about table-per-subclass that Subclass dont use parents fields. Do i have to declarete it implicity?

Comment: Database do not have FK to the associated columns of the Base table(( So. If i dont have FK on Basic table its impossible to realize inheritance there?

Comment: Hm.... It is very strange coz i have only 1 guery for sequence for 2 entities. But the difference in ids is 1 still...

Comment: Got it. Made bi-directional @OneToOne

Comment: Great. And the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn still does the parent-child link then.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to reproduce your problem. Can you be more specific on what is your join strategy? Is it `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` or `InheritanceType.JOINED`? Nonetheless I managed to prepare complete example with TABLE-PER-CLASS join strategy which does increment the sequence only once when you persist `SubDepartment`. Maybe it helps.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CompoundPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Department {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XXX")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "XXX", sequenceName = "XXX",  allocationSize = 1)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}


@Entity
public class SubDepartment extends Department {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class CompoundPK implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Long version;

    public CompoundPK() {
    }

    public CompoundPK(Long id, Long version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    // hashCode & equals
}
```

Comment: Is this possible with `InheritanceType.JOINED` strategy? and how?